# Index for one column only for specific other column value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

I' ve got table logs, where there are, among others, two fields: `action` (VARCHAR 45) and `info` (VARCHAR 10000).

There are multiple things logged to this table, and one of them is user ip when visiting page. For this situation `action`='ip', `info`='IP.ADD.RE.SS'.

Because `info` can have some big amount of text for specific things logged, I would like to only create INDEX that works for `info` field for `action`='ip' only so I can search for IP's quickly and do not have overgrown index with "actions".

I've already tried creating INDEX for first 15 characters, but still IP entries are about 1% of all stuff, and it seems a bit overkill for me.
This entire solution has been inherited from someone else, and unfortunately there is little I can do right now to change entire architecture

Any sugestion how to do it right way? Is it even possible?

Comment: If only I had a nickel for every time I've heard, "we inherited the data model and we can't change it at this time..." :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some RDBMS products support what you're describing. It's called [partial or filtered indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_index) by different products.

- PostgreSQL has [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html)
- Microsoft SQL Server as [filtered indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes)
- SQLite has [partial indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html)

MySQL does not implement this idea (they are under no obligation to implement it, since it's a nonstandard feature). There has been a request for this as a new feature: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76631

One workaround you can do in MySQL 5.7 to simulate a partial index is to create a virtual column where the value is NULL unless the `action` is 'ip'. Then index that virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE logs
  ADD COLUMN ip_info VARCHAR(12) 
    AS (CASE `action` WHEN 'ip' THEN LEFT(info, 12) END),
  ADD KEY (ip_info);
```

Strictly speaking, that still indexes every row, but at least it doesn't store any of your values in the index except where the action is 'ip'.

P.S.: I haven't tested the above example, so apologies if there are syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fall under the "EAV" category.  You have a bunch of things (ip, postdel, etc), each of which is optional.  Some of them need indexing, some do not.

My recommendation is to put the key-value pairs in a `JSON` string.  And make a special column for any thing that you do want to index (IP, in your case).  It can be `NULLable` in order to minimize (but not totally eliminate the 'wasted' space.

See also my [*blog on EAV*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

See also MySQL's and MariaDB's implementations involving JSON.  Caution: they require relatively new versions of MySQL or MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering on the action column anyway, so a combined index is the solution here. Create an index over both columns `(action, info(15))`.

The order of the columns in the index is important though. Do not change it the other way round.

Comment: Yeah, but in this table there are also entries like:
action='postdel', info='User ID:123 deleted post ID:456' and many other actions with different info.
I assume there is no other way so I do not index unneded action stuff?

Comment: But you're comparing the index to a constant. All this other entries will be filtered out. I honestly don't understand your argument. That's what indexes are for...

Comment: I've made test with data from my test tables. One which contained filtered data and one with full data.
Checked size of indexes and...
| test_acc_logs | action   |                      51003392 |
| test_ip_logs  | action   |                         65536 |

65kB vs 51MB of index size does matter, and production table is 100 timese bigger.
So is it ok to index everything else which is not needed?

Comment: At my workplace we have a table with 21GB of data in it and 32GB of indexes. Question answered? Sometimes it takes what it takes...

Comment: What you should be more concerned about than size of an index, is, if your queries use the index or not. Compare the results of `explain <your query>` with and without this index.